# MX Linux 21. Зависло от команды в терминале

Tags: linux, bash

Первый раз писал bash-скрипт, писал автопрошивальщик для МК. Знаком с этим очень поверхностно, и чтоб понять как что работает, в окне терминала набирал такие команды:

```
$ import a=STC89С52RC
$ import b=${a:0:3}
```

После того как на второй команде нажал ввод, указатель мыши превратился в крестик, а система резко затормозила, а через несколько секунд намертво зависла. После перезагрузки кнопкой сброса работает как обычно.
Очень интересно что произошло, и что такого страшного я набрал.

Comment: для начала вы бы рассказали, что это у вас за программа `import`

Comment: ну это вроде вроде как штатный способ создать переменную в Linux

Comment: перепутали с `export`? только это а) не «способ создать переменную»; б) уж к программе linux точно никакого отношения не имеет. в общем, вы разберитесь, что именно за программа у вас в системе фигурирует под именем import, тогда вам станет понятнее, что у вас в системе происходит.

Comment: Да, вы правы, действительно перепутал

Comment: команда `import` это точно не штатный способ создания переменных, скорее всего эта команда имеет отношение к программе `ImageMagick` - `import - saves any visible window on an X server and outputs it as an image file. You can capture a single window, the entire screen, or any rectangular portion of the screen. The window to capture is selected by clicking the desired window or a program option.`

Comment: Да, это тоже опыт. Теперь знаю, как из под юзера обрушить линух

Comment: Лучше бы баг зарепортили...